# Microsoft Access returns multiple rows, but I only want to display one

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access 2007 to query two separate SharePoint sources.

The first has most of the data I need. The unique ID number for each row in the first has a corresponding column in the second. The ID from the first can occur multiple times in the second. (It's a mapping between two different databases of defects.)first.

What I want to do is this: find all the ID's from table one that occur in the second, and list ID's from the second for each item that corresponds with the first. For starters, I want something a bit like this:

```
Table 1 ID      Table 2 ID's
5               9, 13, 23
10              11, 15
20              8
```

But there's also more data from Table 1 I want to display for each item. 
What I'm getting is this:

```
Table 1 ID      Table 2 ID  Table 1 Data
5               9           Row 5 Additional Data
5               13          Row 5 Additional Data
5               23          Row 5 Additional Data
10              11          Row 10 Additional Data
10              15          Row 10 Additional Data
20              8           Row 20 Additional Data
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Table 1 ID          Table 2 ID's  Table 1 Data
5                   9, 13, 23     Row 5 Additional Data
10                  11, 15        Row 10 Additional Data
20                  8             Row 20 Additional Data
```

Or perhaps:

```
Table 1 ID          Table 2 ID's  
5                   9, 13, 23     
     Row 5 Additional Data
10                  11, 15        
     Row 10 Additional Data
20                  8             
     Row 20 Additional Data
```

How can I create a report like that?

Answer (score 0):

**Comma-separated list from multiple records**

Grouping of multiple data rows into a comma-separated list is not a built-in feature of Access.  There are various ways to do this, but I most often see links to [Allen Browne's tutorial](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

---

**Multi-line row details**

The difference between your last two examples is just a matter of formatting a Form or Report in Design View.  A Report (here capitalized) in Access is a specific type of object for generating custom, formatted views of your data, often for printing or read-only viewing.  A Form is a dynamic, on-screen view of your data.  I suspect that your use of "report" is of a more general sense.

First of all, there is no way to make multiple lines using the default Datasheet View of tables and queries.  To get multiple lines per row of data, you need to create a Form or Report object in Access.  In Design View, you can move the data controls around the detail area to produce multiple lines for each data row.  I suggest searching for tutorials on the web for creating Access Forms and Reports.

See [Guide to designing reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-designing-reports-876a6d27-59aa-467a-8240-ee6e01597291).

Comment: Thanks! The grouping was my real concern; the commas were just a "nice to have". But the last link you provided led to me to look into Grouping Levels, and that seems to be the right path, so I should be able to get something good from here.